# JAVA: Ingresar números consecutivos a un Jtable de acuerdo al contenido de la consulta

Tags: java

necesito otra ayuda, esto ya es de manera estética y para facilitar un poco mas el conteo de el contenido de un jtable, actualmente cargo datos de una bd a un jtable cuyo contenido es variable, lo que yo quiero es que a la hora de realizar la consulta y cargar los datos, en automático me genere el numero consecutivo del contenido sin depender de estarlo guardando en la bd, es decir que al cargar los datos se muestren así:

1 jabón corporal
2 detergente
3 cereal
4 leche
5 huevos

Es decir lo único que extraigo de la bd sea los artículos pero a la hora de mostrarlo en un jtable me genere la secuencia consecutiva de números **(1,2,3,4,5....)** del contenido dentro del jtable, ya busque por Google pero no encuentro algo que me ayude en esto.

Este es una forma con la que cargo mis datos, es un codigo cualquiera:

```
private void tablaCarritoObjetoEncontrado(String noConsultaCargar){
    //actualiza los datos de la tabla realizando una consulta a la base de datos
    String[] columNames = {"FOLIO", "NOMBRE", "PRODUCTOS", "FECHAS A PAGAR"};
    //nombre de columnas, tabla, instruccion sql
    dtTablaAmortizacion = ctrl.getAmortizacionFolio(noConsultaCargar);

    // se colocan los datos en la tabla
     modelo2 = new DefaultTableModel(dtTablaAmortizacion, columNames) {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    carritoPrestamo.setModel(modelo2);
    // Instanciamos el TableRowSorter y lo añadimos al JTable
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> elQueOrdena = new TableRowSorter<>(modelo2);
    carritoPrestamo.setRowSorter(elQueOrdena);
    //Creando mi propio filtro:
    TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(modelo2);
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(""));
    carritoPrestamo.setRowSorter(sorter);
    tablaMaxMin();
}
```

Comment: Los datos que obtienes de la base de datos son nada más los nombres de los productos, y quieres que en java, en el jtable, se muestre un número (consecutivo) asociado a ese producto al lado de su nombre (obtenido de la bd)? Podrías agregar un ejemplo de lo que ya tienes y uno de lo que quieres lograr por favor?

Comment: exactamente, lo único que deseo es que agregue el consecutivo ya que no va a servir ni para ID mas que para saber la cantidad de elementos que hay en el jtable, no plasmo un ejemplo de lo que tengo ya que en si no estoy haciendo algo que contenga esos datos que coloque de ejemplo, hacer las consultas a la bd y cargarlas en el jtable lo hago, lo que ahorita requiero es solo mostrar como un contador para facilitar la cantidad por elemento que existe en el jtable, ando pensando en hacer uso de un ciclo pero quizás dentro de las mismas propiedades de jtable existe alguna función.

Comment: Ok. Sí probablemente JTable tenga algún método o propiedad para saber el número de filas. Sin embargo creo que se sería más sencillo si simplemente el número que asocias a cada producto es su **índice + 1** (su índice en el arreglo o la lista que obtienes de la base de datos). Si deseas saber cuántos elementos hay, nada más habría que consultar la longitud del arreglo `.length` o lista `.size()`.

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta el código de tu TableModel.

Comment: ya agregue un ejemplo

Comment: Me pregunto si ¿habrá algo relevante de `dtTablaAmortizacion` o `getAmortizacionFolio()` por conocer además de los nombres?.

Comment: a que te refieres?

Comment: Esos dos elementos uno es donde se carga para el modelo de la tabla, la informacion y el otro es la consulta a la bd para la informacion, que si desde ahi tengo que implementar ir añadiendo 1,2,3,4, etc creo desde un ciclo pero aun no cacho como, porque en la bd no tengo esa informacion, de echo en si no interesa, simplemente es un agregado mas.